# Is it possible to use a typedef for function DEFINITION?

Tags: c, syntax, typedef

I am routinely using `typedef`s for type and function *declaration*.

Question is: is it possible to *define* a function having a previously declared type (i.e.: signature)?

I mean: given the well known declaration:

```c
void (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(int);
```

or, better, it's (clearer) equivalent:

```
typedef void SigCatcher(int);
SigCatcher *signal(int sig, SigCatcher *func);
```

how is it possible to define a `SigCatcher` function?

of course I can define:

```
void my_sig_catcher(int sig, SigCatcher *func) {
    ...
}
```

but that doesn't make evident this is really a `SigCatcher`.
What I would like is something like:

```
SigCatcher my_sig_catcher {
    ...
}
```

but this is not a valid construct.

Is there some (not too contrived) way to achieve this?

Comment: I would say an almost definite "no".. but let's see if I am wrong on that.

Comment: If it were allowed, it'd still be unusable for functions with parameters, as there'd be no way to name them for use in the function body...

Comment: The declaration of `void my_sig_catcher(int sig, SigCatcher *func)` is not compatible with the declaration `SigCatcher my_sig_catcher` or `void my_sig_catcher(int)`, I guess that `, SigCatcher *func` is just a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. It's not possible, because the language grammar disallows it. The C standard even explicitly states, that it has the intent of disallowing such function definitions in [footnote 162](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note162) mentioned in [6.9.1p2](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9.1p2). I copied the footnote below in the hopes it will clears things up:

```
162) The intent is that the type category in a function definition cannot be inherited from a typedef: 

      typedef int F(void);                          //   type F is ''function with no parameters
                                                    //                  returning int''
      F f, g;                                       //   f and g both have type compatible with F
      F f { /* ... */ }                             //   WRONG: syntax/constraint error
      F g() { /* ... */ }                           //   WRONG: declares that g returns a function
      int f(void) { /* ... */ }                     //   RIGHT: f has type compatible with F
      int g() { /* ... */ }                         //   RIGHT: g has type compatible with F
      F *e(void) { /* ... */ }                      //   e returns a pointer to a function
      F *((e))(void) { /* ... */ }                  //   same: parentheses irrelevant
      int (*fp)(void);                              //   fp points to a function that has type F
      F *Fp;                                        //   Fp points to a function that has type F
```

What's interesting, it's allowed for function declarations. So the following is possible:

```
SigCatcher my_sig_catcher;
```

But the definition has to be:

```
void SigCatcher(int some_name) { /*...*/ }
```